# open second app while twitter login

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I had implemented twitter in two apps with plain auth concept [twitter Authentication](https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth)

It is working fine when only one app is installed in the device. But when both apps are installed in the app then during twitter login from first app, while authorisation control moves to second app.

I have checked both the callback urls and bundle identifiers, they are different for both the apps. But still there is same issue.

I am unable to find the error. If anyone has some idea please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered your apps with Twitter as two different apps? It seems you are using the same for both apps.

Comment: Yup, I have registered two apps with different info